# Launchpad Debian Builder Internet Issues

Tags: packaging, launchpad

I'm packaging a application that curls a file as part of the `debian/rules` file.
It works locally, but on the launchpad Debian package builders I am getting the error: `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: nodejs.org`. Is the internet disabled on the builders? Is there any way to download files?

Comment: Can  you include the `curl` call in question?

Comment: `curl -o /tmp/filename http://url`. I have also seen this issue when npm tries to download packages as well, with every attempt failing with the `cannot resolve host` error. It all works fine locally, so I'm curious about the network configuration on the launcad builders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launchpad builders are not permitted to access any external network resources other than the Ubuntu archive and Launchpad itself, partly to ensure that builds are self-contained and reliable and partly so that Launchpad can't be used to launch attacks on other parts of the internet (remembering that anyone at all can upload code and have it built in a sandboxed environment).  You'll have to embed the file in question in your source package rather than downloading it at build time.